# Add extra line to head section with url as a variable

Tags: magento2, head

I want for every page an additional line in the head section.
The extra line should look like this: `<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.mywebsite.com/us/link.html" hreflang="en-US">` where "**link.html**" is the variable URL and the rest of the line is fixed.

I have tried to accomplish this by adjusting the **default_head_blocks.xml** but I am not a programmer and not familiar with the syntax, can somebody show me the way?

Answer (score 0):

@Ernest you can achieve this using `default.xml` and referencing block `head.additional` , so at your custom module create `view/frontend/layout/default.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="head.additional">
            <block class="< Vendor>\< ModuleName>\Block\Tag" name="my_tags" template="Vendor_ModuleName::tag.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Than create `< Vendor>\< ModuleName>\Block\Tag`

```
<?php

namespace < Vendor>\< ModuleName>\Block;


class Tag extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function getTag()
    {
        $yourVariable = "";
        $tag = '<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.mywebsite.com/us/' . $yourVariable . '" hreflang="en-US">';

        return $tag;
    }
}
```

And last create `view/frontend/templates/tag.phtml` with:

```
<?php
echo $block->getTag();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer, cant get it to work yet, I created a module but so far nothing new in the head, I am probably doing something wrong, as said, I am not a programmer, question: what name do I have to give the file in my module Href/Hreflang/Block/Tag (step 2)?

Comment: In your case would be Href/Hreflang/Block/Tag.php and inside default.xml should be without the .php , as for the other files one is Href/Hreflang/view/frontend/layout/default.xml and  the other Href/Hreflang/view/frontend/templates/tag.phtml

Comment: And I suppose you have already a registration.php and etc/modules.xml

Comment: Great!!! works like a charm...last question the variable $yourVariable needs to be the url of the page its on (the part trailing the countrycode) how do I solve that?

Comment: @Ernest you can check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33955256/get-the-current-page-url-in-magento-2-0 to get you on the way

Comment: Did it work for you? @Ernest